# Recovering from renamed user home directory

Tags: linux-mint, administration

I changed the name of a user home directory, but couldn't specify this as the new home directory for that user with `usermod` until I logged out of that user.

Not having any other user accounts, I gave root a password and went to reboot into root.

I was told sys admin couldn't log in from the login screen. (Is this because I forgot to unlock root?)

I of course couldn't log in as the old user, with its home directory no longer being found.

I tried logging into recovery mode with root and although I could get in, the filesystem was read-only and `usermod -d` said it cannot lock /etc/passwd.

There are no .lock files in /etc.

Any chance of salvaging this install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boot into recovery mode. If the file system is read-only, make it read-write.

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

Comment: One can do that? Wow! Thanks. All good.